# jquery unable to hide appended div

Tags: jquery, function, html, append, hide

I'm attempting to append a div to the body of a site, then hide it by sliding it to the left when a user clicks the close button using jquery.  The site is currently using Drupal 7, and for these purposes directly editing the file is not a possibility.  I am using Optimizely to apply this.

I also need to incorporate the inline styles, unless there is an easy way to style all of these with jquery. I know, there's a ridiculous amount of divs, but it will only work on this site with these classes applied in this order.

I need to append a string of divs, so I am currently doing it as such:

```
$("body").append("<div id=\"faceboxwrap\">
<div id=\"facebox\" style=\"height:500px; width:320px; z-index:99999; position:fixed; margin-left:0px; bottom:20px; background-image:url(..);\">
<div class=\"action-link field-name-field-fa-link\" style=\"float:left; margin-top:360px; padding-right: 10px; \">
<div class=\"field field-name-field-shared-splash-link field-type-link-field field-label-hidden\" style=\"width: 175px; margin-left: 103px; margin-right: auto; top: 38px; background-color: rgb(204, 51, 51); \">
<div class=\"field-items\">
<div class=\"field-item even\">
<a href=\"...\" id=\"trackDonate\" style=\"padding-right: 10px;\">DONATE $10</a>
</div></div></div>\n
<div style=\"text-align: center; width: 100%; color: rgb(121, 121, 121); font-size: 13px; margin-top: 60px; margin-left: 115px;\">
<button id=\"close\" style=\"font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer; text-transform: lowercase; cursor: hand;\"> No thanks </button>
</div></div></div></div>");
```

I have absolutely zero experience with jquery, so is there an easy way to append this code to my page's body and then hide the entire faceboxwrap div by sliding to the left?  I've been trying to do this for over four hours with every trick I can find and I can't make it work.  Any help would be great.  Thanks.

Edit: updated the  id.

Comment: what style does the `#faceboxwrap` have ?

Comment: None, so technically this one div can be removed.  The rest of the divs have styles attached via a stylesheet if they do not contain inline styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#closeButtonId").on("click", function() {
            $("#faceboxwrap").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This should solve your problem.

The [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) methods documentation.

**EDIT: Since the button is created with the divs, here's another solution that might work:**

`<button id=\"close\" style=\"font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer; text-transform: lowercase; cursor: hand;\" onclick=\"$('#faceboxwrap').hide();\">No thanks</button>`

Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22d3a/1/).

Another working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22d3a/3/).

**And now a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22d3a/5/) that does everything you need, hides the div by taking it to the left. You'll need [*jQuery UI*](http://jqueryui.com) to achieve that behaviour though.**

If you need to bind a event on an element that is created after DOM loading I don't think it's possible to bind that event without being obtrusive on your JS code. I'm not a hundred percent sure, but I don't think is possible.

Comment: I don't think so because you're not attaching the click event to these divs, you're attaching to a element that already exists.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/22d3a/) out and see if it helps.

Comment: No, the button is actually contained within these divs `<button id=\"close\" style=\"font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; cursor: pointer; text-transform: lowercase; cursor: hand;\"> No thanks </button>` Are there any other solutions you know of?

Comment: Oh, I see now. I don't think it's possible to attach an event without being obstrusive in your JS code. I'm not sure, about that, but I'll edit my answer with something that might be helpful.

Comment: Unfortunately the edit didn't work either.  Thank you for the help though, I appreciate the effort

Comment: If one of these three fiddles solves your problem, I'd appreciate if you accept my answer and upvote it.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to edit the content of the page that the jquery is being applied to, so I can't add jQuery UI to it.  Is there a work around?

Comment: Did you try the first two fiddles?

Comment: Yes, none of the fiddles work when applied.  I think it's an issue with the way that Optimizely works, I've contacted their support to see if they can help.

Comment: What's Optimizely? And If you need the facebox to be hidden, my two first fiddles do it, don't they?

Comment: Unfortunately no, not through Optimizely for some reason.  Optimizely is an A/B Testing service that allows you to test changes to a site without editing the actual code.  Since the code of the page I'm attempting to run this test on is applied to ~60 of our network's sites, I'm unable to edit the actual code.  If I find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: @user3255115 it's impossible to change a DOM element without doing some code changes. I understand that you cannot include jQuery UI library, but you won't be able to do what you want without code changing.

Comment: I figured it out.  For some reason, changing $('#faceboxwrap').hide(); to jQuery('#faceboxwrap').hide(); in the button's onClick function worked.  I believe this had something to do with the way that Optimizely works.  So, your code worked, it just needed a slight adjustment.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you're using another JS library that also uses $ as global var. Check [jQuery noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) out for more info. I would appreciate if you accept and upvote my answer.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but can't upvote it because I don't have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but you can slide the div to the left with the animate function like this:

```
$("#faceboxwrap").animate({left: newLeft});
```

I assume you want it off the screen and since it's a fixed position you could set

```
newLeft = $("#faceboxwrap").width() * -1
```